# Parsing a file which is separated by "categories"

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my issue:

A) I'm a scripting newbie

B) I have a file where I need the data separated into a CSV style table, I problem is there are three areas of data (see below):

```
(Area 1, not relevant) Total IPv4 packets captured: 2245686
# L4 Protocol   # Packets   Relative Frequency[%]   Protocol description

1   5602       0.249456 Internet Control Message Protocol 
.... (more data here)

(Area 2, relevant) Total TCP packets: 2238186
# Port  # Packets   Relative Frequency[%]   Protocol description

22  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
.... (more data here)

(Area 3, relevant) Total UDP packets: 1623
# Port  # Packets   Relative Frequency[%]   Protocol description

.... (more data here)

(Area 4, relevant) Total SCP packets: 0
# Port  # Packets   Relative Frequency[%]   Protocol description

.... (more data here)
```

(This is a Tranalyzer _protocols output)

So what I need to do is make the output look like:

```
# Port,# Packets,Relative Frequency[%],Protocol description
22,2138555,95.548583,The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol,(more data...)
```

but I also need to take the data from each area and put it in a separate CSV file (TCP, UDP, SCP) so that for all flows I put in the table (each in a different _protocols file in different subdirectories) the data can go into one of these 3 files and build what will be a memory-crushing spreadsheet (hence why a CSV.)

I'm also completely open to any other way to represent this anyone can suggest.

Much appreciated!

Comment: This is unclear.  You need to provide additional examples everywhere you have "more data...", especially in the output.  Why are there additional fields after the "Protocol description" column without corresponding header(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command will extract and convert the data file to a csv.
Change `x` to TCP, UDP or SCP to extract particular set of data.
Change `<analyzer_output.txt>` to proper file name before executing.

```
x="SCP"; \
cat <analyzer_output.txt> | sed "1,/^Total $x/d; /^Total /,\$d; /^\s*$/d" | \
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\s\+\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g; s/\([0-9]\)\s\+\([A-Za-z]\)/\1,\2/g' \
> $x.csv
```

Resulting SCP.csv file for below sample data

```
41,2138555,95.548583,The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
42,2138555,95.548583,The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
```

Sample data file

```
Total IPv4 packets captured: 2245686
1   5602       0.249456 Internet Control Message Protocol
2   5602       0.249456 Internet Control Message Protocol

Total TCP packets: 2238186
21  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
22  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol

Total UDP packets: 1623
31  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
32  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol

Total SCP packets: 0
41  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
42  2138555   95.548583 The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
```

Comment: You are a Saint! Thank you.